# Use SQL Server Management Studio with Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: tfs, ssms, azure-devops

I want to use SSMS 2012 with a TFS solution in Visual Studio Online. I have a Windows 10 x64 machine running Visual Studio 2015.

By following the steps from [this tutorial](https://devjef.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/source-control-using-visual-studio-online-in-ssms/) I installed the 32bit version of the MSSCCI provider (as SSMS is a 32bit application).

However when I attempt to add the solution in SSMS I get the following error:

Unexpected error encountered. It is recommended you restart the application as soon as possible.

```
Error: No such interface supported
File: vsee\internal\inc\vscomptr.inl
Line number: 259
```

A restart does not fix this. So my questions are:

1. Has anyone got this working?
2. There does not appear to be a Team Explorer window inside SSMS, so how do you see what is checked out and also easily check things in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, and it should be fixed in [Cumulative Update 3 of SQL Server 2012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2723749). More details, check this KB article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2727824.

Comment: Spot on thanks. Any ideas as to how to bring up the Team Explorer window in SSMS?

Comment: There is no Team Explorer window in SSMS. To use Source Control with SSMS, you need to go to File menu, point to Source Control and then click the appropriate option.